# libmemcached path?

Tags: mysql, memcached, libmemcache, libmemcached

Trying to follow these instructions:
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ha-memcached-interfaces-mysqludf.html)

```
shell> tar zxf memcached_functions_mysql-1.1.tar.gz
shell> cd memcached_functions_mysql-1.1
shell> # If memcached library is not found, set LDFLAGS=-Llibrary_directory before next command.
shell> ./configure --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

When I run:

```
sudo ./configure --with-mysql=/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config
```

I get this at the end of output:

```
checking for libmemcached >= 0.17... configure: error: libmemcached not found
```

So I tried to set LDFLAGS as instructed above but don't know the "library_directory" path.

How can I find it?

Update 1: As per response below. libmemcached IS installed:

```
sudo yum install libmemcached
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, replace, rhnplugin, security
epel                                                                                                       | 3.7 kB     00:00     
ius                                                                                                        | 2.2 kB     00:00     
rackspace-rhel-x86_64-server-5.6.z-common                                                                  |  871 B     00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-5.6.z                                                                                   | 1.3 kB     00:00     
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Package libmemcached-0.31-1.1.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `libmemcached-devel`, it probably needs headers too.

Comment: Now i get...args.c:7:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory on "sudo make" will open a new ticket