# "sudo make" returns error memcache setup

Tags: mysql, memcached, redhat, libmemcache, libmemcached

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890826/libmemcached-path).

I was able to `./configure` after installing libmemcache-devel, but now when I move to the next setup and run `sudo make` I get the following:

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/tmp/memcached_functions_mysql-1.1/src'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/tmp/memcached_functions_mysql-1.1/src'
/bin/sh ../libtool --preserve-dup-deps --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I/usr/include/mysql  -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv    -g -O2 -MT args.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/args.Tpo -c -o args.lo args.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I/usr/include/mysql -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -g -O2 -MT args.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/args.Tpo -c args.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/args.o
args.c:7:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
In file included from args.c:12:
common.h:19: error: expected ')' before '*' token
args.c:16: error: expected ')' before '*' token
args.c:82: error: expected ')' before '*' token
make[2]: *** [args.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/tmp/memcached_functions_mysql-1.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/tmp/memcached_functions_mysql-1.1/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing mysql development packages, in your case `mysql-devel`.

Comment: i did try it said I had to wait 7 mins to accept. Now I'm not able to locate the plugin_dir show variables like 'plugin_dir'; returns blank location