# How to fix?: mysql> show variables like 'plugin_dir'; Does not show plugin_dir location

Tags: mysql, memcached, redhat, libmemcache, libmemcached

After this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891384/sudo-make-returns-error-memcache-setup) I continued to try to setup MySQL memcached User-Defined Functions as per these instructions:
http://stanley-huang.blogspot.com/2010/04/level-3-install-memcached-user-defined.html

But now when trying to find the plugin_dir location I get:

```
mysql> show variables like 'plugin_dir';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| plugin_dir    |       | 
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It's blank. What did I miss?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
plugin_dir=/path/to/plugin/directory
```

Comment: There's none set in my.cnf Safe to set one?

Comment: @mattl My sysadmin has done this for me, but the `plugin_dir` variable is still blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for this:

```
select @@plugin_dir;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).